# CodeCoverage using Chutzpah for AngularJS TestCases

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, chutzpah

I have been using Chutzpah  to see the CodeCoverage for my TestCases

My question is whether my code coverage command should also include those UnitTestCases? For example if there are 100 js which has the testcases whether they should be included as part of CodeCoverage or excluded? I am confused

Comment: What do you mean? The code coverage is a measure of the amount of the *production code* that gets executed when running the *test code*. Therefore unless you have tests for the tests, a coverage value for the test code wouldn't be meaningful.

Comment: That's what exactly I thought but got confused